# Merge two array which have different number of properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two javascript array which have different numbers of properties as follwoing.

**Arrary 1.**

```
var arrFirst = [{
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "May-31-2012",
    'value1': 56
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Jun-05-2014",
    'value1': 36
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Nov-28-2015",
    'value1': 29
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Dec-01-2017",
    'value1': 58
  }];
```

**Array 2.**

```
var arrSecond = [{
    'date': "May-31-2012",
    'value2': 26
  }, {
    'date': "Jun-05-2015",
    'value2': 78
  }, {
    'date': "Nov-28-2015",
    'value2': 560
  }, {
    'date': "Dec-01-2016",
    'value2': 56
  },
   {
    'date': "Dec-04-2016",
    'value2': 36
  }];
```

I would like to merge these two array and create one array based on **date**.
Result array should be as following.

```
var resultArray = [{
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "May-31-2012",
    'value1': 56,
    'value2': 26
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Jun-05-2014",
    'value1': 36,
    'value2' :0
  },{
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Jun-05-2015",
    'value1': 0,
    'value2' :78
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Nov-28-2015",
    'value1': 29,
    'value2': 560
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Dec-01-2016",
    'value1': 0,
    'value2' : 56
  },{
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Dec-01-2016",
    'value1': 0,
    'value2' : 56
  },{
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Dec-04-2016",
    'value1': 0,
    'value2' : 56
  }];
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: If it was up to me, I would use the date as the 'key' and iterate both arrays to create a new array and populate the array with the right properties.

Comment: Is it possible to use a javascript Date object? These can be compared to get the latter Date. This would be a lot less work than sorting those strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create new objects with a default value for  not given properties and iterate the given data and use a hash table for assigning values to the same date.

Then sort the result array by date.

```js
var arrFirst = [{ name: 'A', date: "May-31-2012", value1: 56 }, { name: 'A', date: "Jun-05-2014", value1: 36 }, { name: 'A', date: "Nov-28-2015", value1: 29 }, { name: 'A', date: "Dec-01-2017", value1: 58 }],
    arrSecond = [{ date: "May-31-2012", value2: 26 }, { date: "Jun-05-2015", value2: 78 }, { date: "Nov-28-2015", value2: 560 }, { date: "Dec-01-2016", value2: 56 }, { date: "Dec-04-2016", value2: 36 }],
    merged = [arrFirst, arrSecond].reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            a.forEach(function (o) {
                if (!hash[o.date]) {
                    hash[o.date] = { date: o.date, name: 'A', value1: 0, value2: 0 };
                    r.push(hash[o.date]);
                }
                Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                    hash[o.date][k] = o[k];
                });
            });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

merged.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getISODate(s) {
        var month = { Jan: '01', Feb: '02', Mar: '03', Apr: '04', May: '05', Jun: '06', Jul: '07', Aug: '08', Sep: '09', Oct: '10', Nov: '11', Dec: '12' };
        return s.slice(7, 11) + '-' + month[s.slice(0, 3)] + '-' + s.slice(4, 6);
    }
    return getISODate(a.date).localeCompare(getISODate(b.date));
});

console.log(merged);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to merge 2 array

```
     var arrFirst = [{
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "May-31-2012",
    'value1': 56
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Jun-05-2014",
    'value1': 36
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Nov-28-2015",
    'value1': 29
  }, {
    'name': 'A',
    'date': "Dec-01-2017",
    'value1': 58
  }];
    var arrSecond = [{
    'date': "May-31-2012",
    'value2': 26
  }, {
    'date': "Jun-05-2015",
    'value2': 78
  }, {
    'date': "Nov-28-2015",
    'value2': 560
  }, {
    'date': "Dec-01-2016",
    'value2': 56
  }, {
    'date': "Dec-04-2016",
    'value2': 36
  }];

function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) {
            var a1 = [];
            if(arr1 && arr2) {
                if(arr1.length >= arr2.length) {
                  arr1.forEach(function(e, k, i) {
                    a1.push(k);
                    a1[k] = [];
                    a1[k] = merge(e, arrSecond[k]);
                  });
                } else {
                  arr2.forEach(function(e, k, i) {
                    a1.push(k);
                    a1[k] = [];
                    a1[k] = merge(e, arrFirst[k]);
                  });
                }
            } else {
                if(arr1) {
                a1 = arr1;
              }
              if(arr2) {
                a1 = arr2;
              }
            }
            return a1;
        }

function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1 && arr2) {
    return Object.assign(arr1, arr2);
  } else {
    if(arr1) {
        return arr1;
    } 
    if(arr2) {
    return arr2;
    }
  }
}

console.log(mergeArrays(arrFirst, arrSecond));
```

then just put both array to mergeArrays like mergeArrays(arrFirst, arrSecond); and it will give you merged result

You can see live demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/eRjeZ/13/

Hope this help you

Answer (score -1):

This will help u.

```
 var resultArray = arrFirst.concat(arrSecond);
```